# I want to edit the tags template by adding text that displays all tags from the listed posts

Tags: taxonomy, tags, page-template

So I have tag "Iphone", I enter on page of this tag and there I get the:

1. h1
2. description
3. Listed posts that have this tag

I want to add between description and listed posts the sentence:

You can also read about: - other tags that listed posts have separated with commas-

Final Result will be:

1. H1
2. Description
3. You can also read about:- other tags that listed posts have separated with commas -
4. Listed posts that have this tag

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We love to help you. But! This question doesn't even contain a question nor does it contain context or code that tells us what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck. Please read the [Help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn to ask a good question and then update your question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: So if the posts tagged with `iphone` were also tagged `ios`, `apple`, `tutorial` (for example), you want number three to only show: "**You can also read about: `ios`, `apple`, `tutorial`**" but `iphone` would not be listed with them, correct?